Why $\xi X$ and $\xi |X|$ have the same distribution?
Let $\xi$ be an Rademacher random variable or symmetric Bernoulli random variable.
Let $X$ be another random variable that is independent of $\xi$.
I want to show that $\xi X$ and $\xi |X|$ have the same distribution.
My first attempt is to show that they have the same distribution function. In deed, let $a \geq 0$,
\begin{align}
 P(\xi|X| \leq a) &= \frac{1}{2} P(|X| \leq a) + \frac{1}{2}P(|X| \geq - a)\\\\
   &= \frac{1}{2}P(|X| \leq a) + \frac{1}{2}\\\\
   &= \frac{1}{2}(P(X\leq a) - 1 + P(X \geq -a)) + \frac{1}{2}\\\\
   &= \frac{1}{2}P(X \leq a) + \frac{1}{2}P(X \geq - a)\\\\
   &= P(\xi X \leq a)
\end{align}
I believe this proves the case when $a$ is positive. However, when I try $a < 0$, this method does not lead me to anywhere.

One approach would be to start with thinking about $X = \text{sign}(X), |X|$. You might want to consider  what $\xi$ does to the distribution of $\text{sign}(X)$ (if $X$ may be discrete, don't forget the possibility that $X=0$).

@Glen's suggestion is an excellent one.  Another, albeit a little less elementary, provides some insight: because it is obvious (and easily shown) that because both $\xi X$ and $\xi|X|$ have distributions symmetric about $0,$ their distributions are determined by the distributions of their absolute values, both of which equal $|X|,$ QED.
